# Get objects at index out of List<Object>

Tags: c#, list, object, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a 2D RPG game, and would like to use a List< List< Object > > to make a grid in which I store world objects of different types. Only problem is, that I don't know how to get stuff out of this multidimensional List.

The code below creates a multidimensional List and fills it with 'Dirt' Objects (though objects[i] doesnt work, which is my problem).

```
    public List<List<Object>> objects;

        this.mapWidth = 36;
        this.mapHeight = 21;
        this.objects = new List<List<Object>>();

        for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
        {
            objects.Add(new List<Object>());
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < mapWidth; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < mapHeight; j++)
            {
                objects[i].Add(new Dirt());
            }
        }
```

The players has a position, e.g. 18,11, which is in the middle of this map/multidimensional List. I would like to check which 'tiles' are around him so I only have to update those things on the map. List[y][x] doesnt work.

Comment: Don't know how to _get_ items out from the collection? You mean something like `Dirt gridSpace = objects[18][11]`?

Comment: What are you attempting to do with it? Is `Object` the same as `System.Object`?

Comment: It should work as @ChrisSinclair says.
Make sure to validate if the first index is null first.

If(objects[i] != null && objects[i][j] != null){ 
Foo myFoo = objects[i][j];
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your initial construction code is incorrect. Looks like you're building your grid to have `mapHeight` rows *and* `mapheight` columns. Rewrite the construction code to be this:

```
for (var y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
{
    objects.Add(new List<Object>());
    for (var x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
    {
        objects[y].Add(new Dirt());
    }
}
```

EDIT: And I think this will produce a table where your lookup can be achieved by: `Object gridEntry = objects[y][x];`

EDITx2: If you like, you can rewrite the creation code to this:

```
for (var y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
{
    List<Object> currentRow = new List<Object>();
    objects.Add(currentRow);
    for (var x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
    {
        currentRow.Add(new Dirt());
    }
}
```